# Phone call action using Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a web mobile app with Jquery Mobile, and i put this phone call button in meu toolbar:

```
 <button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-phone">Ligar</button>
```

I 'm having difficulty to finding a tutorial that teach how can i create a call action to my number in cellphones.

Answer (score 0):

I found.

i will user my example

```
<button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-phone"><a href="tel:+1800229933(YOUR NUMBER)">Call</a></button>
```

then add:

```
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-rim-auto-match" content="none">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="tel:5551234567">Call Me</a>
```